# How to merge 2 object in javascript without overwriting and using both's value?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with 2 objects, like:

first object:

```
{
'relic': StackClass { name: 'relic', version: '1'},
'web': StackClass { name: 'web', version: '390'},
'media': StackClass { name: 'media', version: '107'},
'cloak': StackClass { name: 'cloak', version: '3'}
}
```

second object:

```
{
'relic': StackClass { name: 'relic', version: '1'},
'media': StackClass { name: 'media', version: '107'},
'web': StackClass { name: 'web', version: '399'},
'cloak': StackClass { name: 'cloak', version: '1'}
}
```

my final should be like this:

```
{
'web': StackClass { name: 'web', version: '390', version: '399'},
'cloak': StackClass { name: 'cloak', version: '3', version: '1'}
}
```

So the stack's name are the same, but their version may be different.

My have-to-do is merging these objects without overwriting.
Where the names are the same, so everywhere, I have to check the versions, and where the versions are different, I need to put that stack into the final object with both version.
Where the versions are the same, I don't need those stacks.

I've tried with _.merge(object, [sources]) and vanilia js.

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You can't have two property with same name in object at same level

Comment: You can't have two properties with the same name (`version`) and different values. You'll need to make any such properties a single property with an array value. (And you'll want to be consistent, doing that even if they have only one value, because inconsistent object trees tend to be poor practice.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Yes, that's why I was looking for another solution. I've found it out, as I tried to make it work. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object **cannot** have multiple same property.

But you can merge them into an array. so if there are multiples same properties accross your 2 object, it will put them in an array.

```js
const obj1 = {name : "John" , version : 300};
const obj2 = {job : "Dev" , version : 301};

let obj3 = {...obj1};

for(let key in obj2){
  if(obj3.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    obj3[key] = [obj3[key], obj2[key]];
  }else{
    obj3[key] = obj2[key];
  }
}

console.log(obj3);
```

Comment: thank you!
array is okay, object is not necessary as final solution.
Thanks,thanks!!!!

Comment: Cool, don't forget ti put it as "Solved", it may helps others